# Responsive design script handling using yepnope

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, internet-explorer-7, yepnope

At the footer of my responsive site I have tried to load different scripts for mobile and desktop using yep-nope and underscrore.js

```
var $window = $(window)
,throttled = _.throttle( packageLoader, 500);
$window.resize( throttled );
```

When the browser window is resized, the above function is triggered. It waits 500ms then fires off the "packageLoader function.

```
<script src="/assets/javascripts/yepnope.1.5.4-min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/javascripts/underscore-min.js"></script>

function packageLoader(){

    Modernizr.load([
        {
            test: Modernizr.mq('(max-width:768px)'),
            yep: 
            [
                '/assets/javascripts/zepto.min.js',
                '/assets/javascripts/common-portable.js'
            ],
            nope:
            [
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
                // Accommodation guide plugins
                '/assets/javascripts/jquery.nouislider.min.js',
                '/assets/javascripts/jquery.cycle2.min.js',
                // END Accommodation guide plugins
                '/assets/javascripts/common-desktop.js'
            ],
            both: 
            [
                '/assets/javascripts/main.js'
            ]
        }
    ]);
}

window.onload = packageLoader();
```

The Problem:

IE7 +

I need a good solution to manage scripts that are running at different window sizes - I want the mobile site to be as light as possible. SO I believe that I need a way of.

• loading jQuery either from the cache or the file if not present.
• loading zepto if user is viewing with a mobile
• handling scripts

The above script may not be the best solution, if you have built a site that requires this control before let me know what libraries you have used please..

Much appreciation in advance

Comment: You have probably moved on by now, but why are you bothering with IE7 from a responsive standpoint (and IE8 for that matter) they don't work in a mobile context so whats the point in working your backside off to support them in this way? unless i am missing an obvious point

Comment: yep - I fix the width of the sites for IE6-7 even 8 .. and only let modern standard compliant browsers have the flashy stuff. I still however haven't found a great way of dividing up the JS for different viewport sizes ---

Comment: have you used jrespond or is that way off what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

yepnope has been depreciated, in fact it won't be in the next version of modernizer by default.

You might have better luck just concat-ing those scripts together and uglify-ing them. I'd worry about additional http requests/minification (images, script and css file) before I'd stress about the size of a script file.